# How to change an Avro field from mandatory to optional when using the schema registry?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

One field (`abc` below) of my Avro record type was initially mandatory, and I tried to change it to allow null values, but I am getting this error:

```
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: 
Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject.

details: [Incompatibility{type:TYPE_MISMATCH, location:/, message:reader type: 
RECORD not compatible with writer type: NULL*
```

This is the old schema:

```json
    {
        "type": "record",
        "namespace": "com.model.avro",
        "name": "AbcPayloadV1",
        "version": "1",
        "fields": [{
                    "name": "abc",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "OldData",
                    "type": [{
                            "type": "record",
                            "name": "Abcde",
                            "namespace": "com.model.avro",
                            "fields": [{
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "string"
                            }]
    
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

This is new Schema:

```json
    {
        "type": "record",
        "namespace": "com.model.avro",
        "name": "AbcPayloadV1",
        "version": "1",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "abc",
                "type": "string"
            },
        
            {
                "name": "OldData",
                "type": [{
                    "type": "record",
                    "name": "Abcde",
                    "namespace": "com.model.avro",
                    "fields": [{
                            "name": "id",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    ]
                }, "null"]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message comes from the schema registry which is complaining that making such change is not forward compatible and could possibly break some downstream consuming application.

Not being forward compatible means that, assuming there exists some consumer applications somewhere that still rely on the old schema (simply because they've not been updated yet), they would not be able to process records produced with the new schema, because those records could have nulls at a location where the old consumer is expecting a mandatory value.

With forward compatibility checks turned on in the schema registry, you can never remove a field from the schema nor make a mandatory one optional.

Depending on your project, maybe a solution to your issue would be to decrease the compatibility requirements for that schema to just `BACKWARD` or `BACKWARD_TRANSITIVE`, although that assumes you have a deployment process in place to make sure all the consumers are updated before updating the producers, to prevent the situation I describe above.

See also more details here:

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html#forward-compatibility

Comment: schema is FORWARD_TRANSITIVE

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Then this confirms it: a `FORWARD_TRANSITIVE` compatibility mode in the schema registry forbids to change a field from mandatory to optional. That's because such change is not forward compatible.